condition to apply integration by parts?
I have two real functions $f, g$ defined on $[a,b]$. Both functions are differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$.
Is this enough to apply integration by parts
$$
\int_{a}^b f(x) g(x) dx =  f(b) G(b) - f(a) G(a) - \int_a^b f'(t) G(t) dt, 
$$
where $G(t) = \int_{a}^t g(x) dx$.
My concern is that in the integral expression $f'$ may not be well defined at the end points... Does this matter? Thank you!

Is taking a one-sided limit allowed? That would be a first try for me.

No, it does not matter. The (Riemann-)integral over the set $(a,b)$ is the same as the (Riemann-)integral over $[a,b]$.

Since it’s an integral, it suffices that f’ is well-defined arbitrarily near the endpoints (within the interval, ofc)

No, it does not matter. The Riemann integral over the set $(a,b)$ is the same as the Riemann integral over $[a,b]$. In elementary words, you could say, that single points (you ask about $a$ and $b$) have "no width" and therefore do not contribute to the surface under the function $f'(t)G(t)$. So no matter which values $f'(a)G(a)$ and $f'(b)G(b)$ have, they do not change the value of the integral
$$\int_a^bf'(t)G(t) dt$$
In fact, you could even change the function $f'(t)G(t)$ at as many points as you wish, as long it remains continuous almost everywhere between $a$ and $b$.
